# SpriteKit updating label

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this code below and I just want to make a simple addition game that prints out the money when you tap. I have it set to print out the currentMoney variable which is 0 + 5 and so on but I can not get the label to change with it.

I tried setting `myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)` in the touches began but it will not update `myLabel`, how can I achieve this?

```
import SpriteKit

var currentMoney = 0

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
        myLabel.fontSize = 45
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        currentMoney = currentMoney + 5
        print(currentMoney)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the text because you can't access you label outside the moveToView function. Try this:

```
    import SpriteKit

    var currentMoney = 0
    var myLabel: SKLabelNode! //made it globally

    class GameScene: SKScene {
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            /* Setup your scene here */
            myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
            myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
            myLabel.fontSize = 45
            myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        currentMoney = currentMoney + 5
        myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)

        print(currentMoney)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the change of `currentMoney` variable and take appropriate actions (update label's text property). To do this, you can make a label as a property of your scene, and use `didSet` property observer like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var currentMoney = 0 {

    didSet{
        myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
    }
}

let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

    self.addChild(myLabel)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    currentMoney = currentMoney + 5
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
```

```
let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
var currentMoney = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    /* Setup your scene here */

    myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(myLabel)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    currentMoney = currentMoney + 5
    print(currentMoney)

    myLabel.text = String(currentMoney)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}